# unable to insert file name to sql using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have created form that store input text and file name to `sql` in my processing i do multiple images to rename and save path to `sql`, Now my problem is when i process form without adding image input text are stored to `SQL` and image random code are stored to SQL

when i add image and submit form i don't get Error and no data is transfered to `SQL`

### PROCESSING CODE

```
    try {
#connection 
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=localtest', $db_username, $db_password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $data = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO mobileadd (mcat, mtype, mtitle, files1, files2, files3, files4, files5, description, mmodel, modelnumber, alsoinclude, mcondition, price, youare, mname, email, phone, ylocation, ystreet) VALUES (:mcat, :mtype, :mtitle, :files1, :files2, :files3, :files4, :files5, :description, :mmodel, :modelnumber, :alsoinclude, :mcondition, :price, :youare, :mname, :email, :phone, :ylocation, :ystreet)');
        $mcat = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'mcat', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
        $mtype = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'mtype', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
        $mtitle = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'mtitle', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
        $files1= filter_input(INPUT_POST, "$newname$file1", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
        $files2= filter_input(INPUT_POST, "$newname$file2", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
        $files3 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "$newname$file3", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
        $files4 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "$newname$file4", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
        $files5 =filter_input(INPUT_POST, "$newname$file5", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
        $description = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'description', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
        $mmodel = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'mmodel', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
        $modelnumber = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'modelnumber', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
        $alsoinclude = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'alsoinclude', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
        $mcondition = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'mcondition', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
        $price = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'price', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
        $youare = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'youare', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
        $mname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'mname', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
        $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
        $phone = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'phone', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
        $ylocation = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ylocation', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
        $ystreet = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ystreet', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
        $data->execute(array(':mcat'=>$mcat, ':mtype'=>$mtype,':mtitle'=>$mtitle, ':files1' =>$files1, ':files2' =>$files2, ':files3' => $files3, ':files4' =>$files4, ':files5' => $files5, ':description'=>$description, ':mmodel'=>$mmodel, ':modelnumber'=>$modelnumber, ':alsoinclude'=>$alsoinclude, ':mcondition'=>$mcondition, ':price'=>$price, ':youare'=>$youare, ':mname'=>$mname, ':email'=>$email, ':phone'=>$phone, ':ylocation'=>$ylocation, ':ystreet'=>$ystreet));
#exception handiling
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: Does it echo the message from the exception? If so what is the error message? If not did you check your logs to see if there are other errors? Did you dump the values of all the parameters to see if they are acceptable before you try an insert them?

Comment: @prodigitalson i don't get error message and i get only empty processing page and no data is processed to sql

Comment: Those `filter_input` calls are unnecessary and probably harmful if you're using PDO variable binding.

Comment: @tadman so what do i do how to change

Comment: I don't know. You haven't posted what `filter_input` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**remove these lines from your code**

```
        $files1= filter_input(INPUT_POST, "$newname$file1", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
        $files2= filter_input(INPUT_POST, "$newname$file2", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
        $files3 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "$newname$file3", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
        $files4 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "$newname$file4", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
        $files5 =filter_input(INPUT_POST, "$newname$file5", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);`
```

and edit data execute linle like this

```
$data->execute(array(':files1' => $newname.$file1))
```

and everything is perfect